# How to automatically increase partition value when using VALUE partitioning?

Tags: dolphindb

When using HASH partitioning, I don't need to consider how many partition values are in advance. When using VALUE partitioning, can I automatically create new partitions if there are new partition values?

Answer (score 0):

From version 0.97.0, DolphinDB supports the feature you want as long as your set the parameter `newValuePartitionPolicy` to `add` in configuration file.